# How to show that there exists a tournament of size n with a certain number of Hamiltonian paths?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Assuming a tournament of size $n$ is a choice of orientation for each edge of
$K_n$, show that there exists a tournament of size $n$ with at least $\dfrac{n!}{2^{n-1}}$
Hamiltonian paths.

This question was on my graph theory final and I wasn't quite sure how to prove this. I think it might have something to do with the out-degrees of a particular node, but I'm not quite sure. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your title asks about a tournament with a **minimum** number of Hamiltonian paths. That would be the transitive tournament, which has just one Hamiltoniam paths. Did you mean **maximum**?

Comment: The usage of 'minimum' is misleading. The title should be changed to "with at least a certain number of Hamiltonian paths".

Comment: Edited to improve quality of the question.